# Invalid CSRF Token 'null' when i using PUT method with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring

this is my javascript.
i'm trying to send PUT message edit.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/questions/" + _questionId + "/answers/" + answerId + "/edit",
        method: "put",
        data: {
            id : answerId,
            body : body,
            "${_csrf.parameterName}": "${_csrf.token}"
        }
```

and this is Server code.

```
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or principal == #answer.content.user")
@RequestMapping(value = "/questions/{questionId}/answers/{answerId}/edit", method = PUT)
void editAnswer(@PathVariable(value = "questionId") Question question, @AuthenticationPrincipal CurrentUser currentUser,
                AnswerForm answerForm, @PathVariable("answerId") String answerId) {

    answerService.edit(answerForm, currentUser.getUser());
}
```

and Controller is PUT method

when i tried with POST method, it works.
but i just change Method(PUT) server and client.
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' WITH 403 forbidden on broswer console.

help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the CSRF token in the PUT request body is not recognized (Servlet containers do not generate a parameter map from PUT request bodies).

But you can send it as [HTTP header](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/questions/" + _questionId + "/answers/" + answerId + "/edit",
    method: "put",
    headers: { "${_csrf.parameterName}": "${_csrf.token}" },
    data: {
        id : answerId,
        body : body,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://gist.github.com/ilake/3656567.  I encountered a similar problem.  If I use POST method, put the `<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />` will work. However, if I use PUT method in ajax. It is not working. Then I use the headers approach. The header name should be `X-CSRF-TOKEN, not`${_csrf.parameterName}`.
Please try this code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/questions/" + _questionId + "/answers/" + answerId + "/edit",
method: "put",
headers: { "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "${_csrf.token}" },
data: {
    id : answerId,
    body : body,
} });
```